# AttributeError when running dc.load command (ESA WorldCover Classification Notebook)

Tags: google-earth-engine, open-data-cube

This issue was raised at [Git Hub](https://github.com/ceos-seo/odc-gee/issues/3) a few months ago, but unfortunately, there is no solution so far. Therefore, I decided to post it here in the hope of attracting the StackExchange community.

I am facing a problem when running the snippet of code below in Google Colab. The code uses the Datacube module from the `odc_gee` package. Here is the link to [the original notebook](https://github.com/ceos-seo/odc-colab/blob/master/notebooks/02.14.01.Colab_LandCover_WorldCover_10m.ipynb).

```py
!wget -nc https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ceos-seo/odc-colab/master/odc_colab.py
from odc_colab import odc_colab_init
odc_colab_init(install_odc_gee=True)

from odc_colab import populate_db
populate_db()

from odc_gee.earthengine import Datacube
dc = Datacube(app='ESA_WorldCover')

product = 'esa_worldcover_google'

# Kumasi, Ghana 
lat_long = (6.7, -1.6)
box_size_deg = 0.50

# Calculates the latitude and longitude bounds of the analysis box
latitude = (lat_long[0]-box_size_deg/2, lat_long[0]+box_size_deg/2)
longitude = (lat_long[1]-box_size_deg/2, lat_long[1]+box_size_deg/2)

dataset = dc.load(product=product,time=time,latitude=latitude,longitude=longitude)
```

After installing required packages, modules and successful authorization at Earth Engine, I run into the following error message after executing las line of code:

> ### /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datacube/utils/geometry/_base.py:519: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: The 'type' attribute is deprecated, and will be removed in the future. You can use the 'geom_type' attribute instead.
> return self.geom.type
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 dataset = dc.load(product=product,time=time,latitude=latitude,longitude=longitude)
>
> 5 frames
> [/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/odc_gee/earthengine.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in load(self, datasets, **kwargs)
> 82         '''
> 83         datasets = datasets if datasets else self.find_datasets(**kwargs)
> ---> 84         return super().load(datasets=datasets, **kwargs)
> 85
> 86     def _refresh_credentials(self, stop_event):
>
> [/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datacube/api/core.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in load(self, product, measurements, output_crs, resolution, resampling, skip_broken_datasets, dask_chunks, like, fuse_func, align, datasets, progress_cbk, **query)
> 292             datasets = self.find_datasets(product=product, like=like, ensure_location=True, **query)
> 293         elif isinstance(datasets, collections.abc.Iterator):
> --> 294             datasets = list(datasets)
> 295
> 296         if len(datasets) == 0:
>
> [/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/odc_gee/earthengine.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in find_datasets(self, limit, **search_terms)
> 119         if hasattr(query, 'asset'):
> 120             images = self.get_images(self.build_parameters(query))
> --> 121             for document in generate_documents(query.asset, images, query.product):
> 122                 if limit != 0:
> 123                     limit = limit - 1 if limit is not None else limit
>
> [/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/odc_gee/earthengine.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in generate_documents(asset, images, product)
> 295     from datacube.index.hl import prep_eo3
> 296     from odc_gee.indexing import make_metadata_doc
> --> 297     for image in images:
> 298         yield prep_eo3(make_metadata_doc(asset, image, product))
> 299
>
> [/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/odc_gee/earthengine.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in get_images(self, parameters)
> 158                 yield response
> 159         except Exception as error:
> --> 160             raise error
> 161
> 162     def build_parameters(self, query):
>
> [/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/odc_gee/earthengine.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in get_images(self, parameters)
> 140         '''
> 141         try:
> --> 142             request = self.ee.data._get_cloud_api_resource().projects().assets().listImages(
> 143                 **parameters)
> 144             while request is not None:
>
> AttributeError: module 'ee.data' has no attribute '_get_cloud_api_resource'

What could be the problem?